# Ember #<Object> has no method 'set'

Tags: json, object, ember.js

I'm extracting JSON data in my routes as follows:

```
App.CollectionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 setupController: function(controller, model){
    $.getJSON('../returnitems.json', function(data){
      controller.set('returnItems', data);
    })
 }
});
```

Which gives me an object I can iterate over in my template with:

```
{{#each destination in controller.returnItems}}
```

Now I want to remove something via a controller with the following code:

```
this.get('controllers.collection').get('returnItems')[returnIndex].set('hasItems', false);
```

Which gives the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
```

But when I use:
    this.get('controllers.collection').get('returnItems')[returnIndex].hasItems = false

it tells me to use get and set?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be doing AJAX calls in the `setupController` hook. You should use the `model` and the `afterModel` hooks so that Ember waits until the promise succeeds before fully transitioning to the route.

Now, you can't call the `set` method because `$.getJSON` returns an array of Plain Old Javascript Objects instead of the array of `Ember.Object`s you're expecting.

Instead you'd do something like this:

```
App.CollectionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 afterModel: function(controller, model) {
    var self = this;
    return $.getJSON('../returnitems.json', function(data_items){
        var items = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data_items.length; i++) {
            items.push(Ember.Object.create(data_items[i]));
        }
        self.set('returnItems', items);
    });
 },
 setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('returnItems', this.get('returnItems'));
 }
});
```

Then you'd be able to:

```
this.get('controllers.collection').get('returnItems').objectAt(returnIndex).set('hasItems', false);
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I still get the error.. it's now this.set('returnItems', items); that gives 
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'
The could the problem be in the object I'm taking? It is valid JSON though..

Comment: It was almost directly helpfull, this.set('returnItems', items); should be self.set with var self declared before return otherwise it is setting it to the getJson and not the (route or model, whichever the this is we want). Thanks!

Comment: My rookie mistake. I've updated the answer. I'm glad it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
this.get('controllers.collection').get('returnItems').objectAt(returnIndex).set('hasItems', false);
```

see: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt

Comment: This also gives the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'set'